# How can I load a file from inside a jar in a static way?

Tags: java, jar

I have a "default" image file that's meant to be used if the "proper" image file doesn't exist. I'm using Maven to create the `jar` and have placed the file under `resources/images`, along with the other images I already have.

The file is defined in a class that has a few defaults:

```
public class Defaults {
    public static final File BLANK_IMAGE = new File(relative_path_to_image);
    //Other defaults
}
```

This works within the IDE, but not if I try to create a `jar` - if I do and run it from the Command Prompt, it spits out the message I wrote for when a specific file can't be found.

I've looked at several potential solutions, but they all rely on non-static methods, which can't be used here since the `File` is static (also, it makes no sense to instantiate something when all its instances would be identical - that's just a waste of time and resources).

Am I just stuck converting the `File` to a `String` and processing it inside every `Object` that needs it with `getResourceAsStream()`?

The file is placed on a few `JLabel` instances (ones that are meant to have images that haven't been created yet) by first converting it into a `BufferedImage`. I mention this in case there are better ways of achieving the same result that bypass the problem I'm having.

Comment: *Am I just stuck converting the File to a String and processing it inside every Object that needs it with getResourceAsStream()?* it's neither a file nor a string. It is a resource inside your jar and that's exactly the call you should use on it. You don't need an instance to call it either. `X.class.getResourceAsStream` will work fine

Comment: I meant if I was stuck using the `File`'s path as a `String` with `getResourceAsStream()` . And it seems like the answer is "yes". Time to rewrite, I suppose. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not really with you on this part of your question. An example argument to that call would be "/images/foo.jpg". Nothing to do with files. That's actually a URL that is relative to the package root. It will work whether or not your app is packaged as a jar

Comment: That's a `String`, yes? It's pretty much the same thing I'd put in the `File` constructor, just a relative path to the image. If that doesn't make sense to you, it's probably because I'm not used to dealing with `jar` files, and it's a moot point anyway because of what you told me about how to accomplish this.

Comment: Oh yes it's a string alright. But read-only application 'files' should always be resources

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's my first time doing something like this (successfully, anyway, I have other questions here where I failed to get a proper runnable `jar`, but that's beside the point), so I'm not sure of the best practices here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new File` means **a file**. An entry in a jar file isn't one. If you mention `File` anywhere in the code, the game is lost immediately.

> (also, it makes no sense to instantiate something when all its instances would be identical - that's just a waste of time and resources).

This mindset is highly detrimental. It leads to writing bad code. Bad in all senses:

- Significantly harder to test.
- Slower to execute. (Lots of fast garbage is actually faster than a few cached objects. Read up on CPU cache behaviour and generational garbage collecting to figure out that 'long lived objects used in many places' is a lot worse than you might think and 'objects that are created and are nearly immediately garbage afterwards' actually costs pretty much nothing whatsoever - the exact opposite of the mindset you appear to still be labouring under).
- Not idiomatic (java is no longer written that way; it makes interacting with other java programmers in terms of code more difficult than it needs to be).
- Not flexible (changing code written with your mindset when requirements change and feature requests pop up, is harder than it needs to be).

> Am I just stuck converting the File to a String and processing it inside every Object that needs it with getResourceAsStream()?

I think you severely misunderstand what `File` is, then. File is just a light wrapper; it has one field, of type String, which represents the path. This:

```java
private static final File MY_IMG_FILE = new File("/foo/bar");

public JLabel codeThatIsInvokedALot() {
  return new JLabel(new ImageIcon(MY_IMG_FILE));
}
```

Is exactly as inefficient as:

```java
public JLabel codeThatIsInvokedALot() {
  return new JLabel(new ImageIcon(MyClass.class.getResource("/foo/bar"));
}
```

In the sense that you pay 1 point for the allocation of some objects, and 100,000,000,000 points (that's not an exaggeration, that is a roughly accurate sense of scale) for opening the jar file (or file on disk) and reading the actual bytes representing the image from it. If you're very very lucky your OS does some disk caching and will turn that into a 1 vs. 1 million gap instead.

If you want 'efficiency', you want to load the **entire image** once. "Create the file object only once" is completely meaningless for performance reasons. A `File` object **does not cache the contents of that file** - just its location, and talking about 'caching' of this doesn't bear talking about (you're caching... about 80 bits worth. The lookup costs 500x more than creating it whole cloth, again not an exagerration).

So how is it done? Not difficult at all:

```java
public class MyImages {
  private final ImageIcon BLANK_IMAGE;

  static {
    BLANK_IMAGE = resourceToImage("/images/blankImage.png");
  }

  public static ImageIcon getBlankImage() { return BLANK_IMAGE; }

  private static ImageIcon resourceToImage(String rsc) {
    return new ImageIcon(MyImages.class.getResource(rsc));
  }
}
```

This will:

- The first time the JVM executes any code that so much as mentions `MyImages`, it'll load the `MyImages` class. Presumably, this will occur not quite 'on boot' but very soon afterwards naturally.
- Any further times any code mentions MyImages, it's already loaded; classes are only loaded at most once.
- Loading MyImages is a heavy duty job - it'll run the static block first (and any other threads that also touch MyImages will be blocked until the first thread is done loading it), and this will actually open up the jar file and read the png file, and decompress it into a raw image map.
- MyImages, the class, will have a relatively sizable memory footprint in the heap due to having to host all those unpacked images.
- `return new JLabel(MyImages.getBlankIcon())` will (unless this is the very first time any code in this JVM execution touches MyImages) execute very quickly and doesn't touch the disk whatsoever.
- I'm pretty sure creating 15 jlabels all with the same icon do not cost significant amounts of memory - they are all using the same underlying unpackaged pixeldata in the one instance of `ImageIcon`.
- Uses the right way to do this: `SomeContextClass.class.getResource`. This is strictly superior to going via the classloader, or using `getClass()` instead of `SomeContextClass.class`: These commonly shown alternatives fail in exotic circumstances (bootloaders, agents, etc - these get a `null` classloader), fail in less exotic circumstances (modular systems where you subclass breaks `getClass()` style), and `MyClass.class.getResource` is simple, succint, idiomatic, and has fewer failure modes than all alternatives.

Comment: Damn, that is a great and thorough explanation. Thank you. Indeed, I did not understand what `File` actually was. What I was taught of Java ends just before creating a GUI and loading images and such, hence the massive gaps in my knowledge and potentially "strange" doubts. Is this safe if there are non-standard characters in the path (accents, for instance) and spaces, or do I need to take other precautions?

Comment: Shuold be safe, yes.

Comment: Then I must be doing something wrong. I'm getting a `NullPointerException` because `getResource()` can't find the image. It works in the IDE (I just need to find a way to resize the images now), but not in the `jar`. For what it's worth, I had to add a leading slash to the String because it wouldn't work anywhere otherwise.

Comment: Yes, the lack of leading slash was a typo, I fixed that. If it doesn't "work" after a build, your build is misconfigured. getting resource "/foo/bar.txt" means that if you run `jar tvf myjar.jar`, /foo/bar.txt should be in there.

Comment: It's there. `images/blank.png` shows up between all the `.class` files and the `META-INF` subfolders and their contents. The actual error says `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null`, in case I misinterpreted the issue.

Comment: You didn't misinterpret. If that's in the jar, `.getResource("/images/blank.png")` __will__ work. You can print `System.out.println(MyClass.class.getResource("MyClass.class"))` to check where it's looking. Perhaps you're not running the jar you think you are? I'm grasping at straws :P

Comment: I tried that with the blank image's URL. It's correct, if I interpreted its formatting correctly. It goes `jar:file:/D:/Programming/Card%20game/Game/target/Game-0.0.1.jar!/images/blank.png`. If I pop open the `.jar`, I can see that the images really are at that location. Perhaps I should open a new question?

Comment: I figured out the problem. All image files are lowercase, but I put the first letter in one file uppercase in the code. I assumed that, like Windows, Java treated file and directory names as case-insensitive, and didn't bother too much with that. I don't know why this worked in the IDE but not in the Command Prompt, but that was the issue. Thank you again for your help.

Comment: If the actual resource is on disk directly (which it will be in IDEs), it's case insensitive if the underlying file system is (so, on normally configured windows and macs, it would work, on linuxen it won't). But jar files are case sensitive, thus, fails then. Good to know, I'll put 'check casing' in my arsenal :)

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to load a file from inside a jar, but the most common way is to use the ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() method.